# Вывод суммы продуктов в TextView

Tags: android, android-textview

У меня есть продукты: картофель, огурец. Я могу добавить их в корзину (для них я создал общую функцию, и в аргументах указал отличие):

```
switch (value){
            case 1:
                oneFunc(R.drawable.potato, 100);
                break;
            case 2:
                oneFunc(R.drawable.ogyrecproduct, 50);
                break;
        }

private void oneFunc(int ImageViewDrawableId, int price) {
    LinearLayout mainLayout = findViewById(R.id.mainmain);
    final ImageButton imageView = new ImageButton(Main2Activity.this); 
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams imageViewLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(450, 150);
    imageView.setImageResource(imageViewDrawableId);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(imageViewLayoutParams);
    mainLayout.addView(imageView);

    TextView pricetext = new TextView(Main2Activity.this);
    pricetext.setText(Integer.toString(price));
    mainLayout.addView(pricetext);

}
```

У каждого продукта есть цена, например, у картофеля цена 100 рублей, у огурца 50 рублей. Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы при добавлении продукта в корзину, в TextView появлялась цена продукта, а при добавлении второго продукта, к старой цене прибавлялась цена второго продукта.
Я не знаю, как реализовать мою задачу. Сделать через HashSet, или нет, или есть ещё какой-нибудь способ. Если есть какие-нибудь вопросы - пишите в комментарии. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84536/discussion-on-question-by------textview).

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю, это решение подойдёт:

```
int totalprice = 0;
switch (value){
            case 1:
                oneFunc(R.drawable.potato, 1);
                break;
            case 2:
                oneFunc(R.drawable.ogyrecproduct, 2);
                break;
        }

private void oneFunc(int ImageViewDrawableId, int id) {
    LinearLayout mainLayout = findViewById(R.id.mainmain);
    final ImageButton imageView = new ImageButton(Main2Activity.this); 
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams imageViewLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(450, 150);
    imageView.setImageResource(imageViewDrawableId);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(imageViewLayoutParams);
    mainLayout.addView(imageView);

    switch (check) {
        case 1:
            totalprice += 218;
            break;
        case 2:
            totalprice += 98;
            break;
    }

    TextView pricetext = new TextView(Main2Activity.this);
    pricetext.setText(totalprice + "");
    mainLayout.addView(pricetext);

}
```

Вместо цены для продукта, я даю ему идентификатор. Программа проверяет, если в корзине есть продукт с идентификатором 1, то мы прибавляем к общей цене 218. Переменная totalprice - глобальная константа, которую мы изменяем.

Comment: Оба свитча проверяют на одни и те же значения, так что их можно объеденить в один. И еще нужно добавить в setText аргумент totalprice. Но в целом да, примерно так  и надо.

Comment: @Эникейщик А, первый свитч вообще находится в onCreate. Продукт добавляется от условия, если value = 1, то добавляется картофель и т.д. Ещё раз спасибо тебе! Очень помог.